# How to show two or more label at centre of the container in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am new for Codenameone Is there any option to align a label depends on another label like align bottom, top, right and left option?

How to align many labels at the centre of the parent layout?

**Here I have attached the code I tried for:**

```
Container center = new Container(new BorderLayout());

    Label des = new Label((String) data.get("title"));
    des.setUIID("MultiLine2");
    center.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH,des);
    Label author = new Label((String) data.get("author"));
    author.setUIID("MultiLine2");
    center.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH,author);

    cnt.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, center);
```

**I am getting outpul like the below image**[image: I am getting outpul like the below image]

**Here I have attached what I need for my project**[image: This is my requirement]

**Can anyone please help me How should I do to get my requirement?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will place the Labels in the absolute center of the container:

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
hi.setLayout(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER_ABSOLUTE));
Container center = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Label line1 = new Label("What are you doing");
Label line2 = new Label("Hello");

center.add(line1);
center.add(line2);

hi.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, center);

hi.show();
```

To adjust the center to move slightly to the left you can add right padding to the center Container:

```
center.getAllStyles().setPadding(Component.RIGHT, 100);
```

Comment: Hi Chen, i'm facing similar problem,so i tried above code its working but in my case both should be in center.. In your solution both are vertical but those are starting from left but in my case all should be in center whether the text is small or big.. can you tell me what i missed?

Answer (score 0):

These two approaches also serve to center labels inside a CN1 container:

```
Container container01 = FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle();
```

and

```
Container container02 = new Container(new GridLayout(2,1));
```

where the number 2 in GridLayout(2,1) refers to the number of labels you have for one column.