# Codename One : Get the current visible image index from a DefaultListModel included in an ImageViewer

Tags: codenameone

I am building an app that makes use of LayeredLayout to display 2 ImageViewers on top of each other. The deeper ImageViewer contains a captured image (a photo) and the shallower one a decoration that the user can change via swiping.

So the decoration images are stored in an ArrayList like this :

```
decorationImageList = new ArrayList<Image>();

    // On filtre les décorations qu'on ajoute à la liste 
    for (String png : res.getImageResourceNames()) {
        if (png.endsWith("-ratio-4-3.png")) {
                decorationImageList.add(res.getImage(png));
        }
    }
```

Then in the StateMachine I load them in the decoration ImageViewer like this :

```
DefaultListModel<Image> decorationModel = new DefaultListModel<Image>(decorationImageList);
findDecorationIV().setImageList(decorationModel);
```

So far it works as expected, the user can swipe to change the decoration.

However I need to know which decoration has been chosen by the user (ie which decoration is currently visible / shown to the user).

I tried to add listeners to the decoration ImageViewer to count the number and direction of swipes but the listeners did not trigger (in the simulator).

```
findDecorationIV().addScrollListener(new ScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void scrollChanged(int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldscrollX, int oldscrollY) {
                System.out.println("There has been some scrolling"); // never triggered

            }
        });
```

or

```
findDecorationIV().addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(Component cmp) {
                System.out.println("Focused lost!"); // never triggered

            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(Component cmp) {
                System.out.println("On focus!"); // triggered only once

            }
        });
```

Now while reading [CN1 doc](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/components.html) I tend to think that I should implement ListModel in my own DecorationModel class, since there is a method called getSelectedIndex. Unfortunately I can't understand how this works and why in their example they do always return 0 in the getSelectedIndex method.

Therefore I am really stuck and looking for help in order to be able and get the current visible decoration shown to the user.

Thanks a lot to whoever may help!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually after doing something else I tried something way simpler than what I tried previously. Indeed a I added a listener (SelectionListener in this case) to the ImageList after loading the decoration model :

```
findDecorationIV().getImageList().addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

                @Override
                public void selectionChanged(int oldSelected, int newSelected) {
                    System.out.println("On vient de sélectionner la décoration suivante " + newSelected);

                }
            });
```

So problem solved!

Comment: Do you know answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430917/how-to-show-two-or-more-label-at-centre-of-the-container-in-codenameone