# Layout composition varying between preview and running app in CN1

Tags: layout, codenameone

I configured a layout with the following result:
The `Layout` of the `Form`'s contentpane is `TableLayout` which consists of one cell. The contentpane has only one container as child for which I set the layoutConstraint with the following modified values: `width = 100%, height = 100%, Align = CENTER, Vertical Align = CENTER`.

In other words, I'm centering the components of the form.

In the preview it looks as expected but not when the app runs in the simulator! 
Note:

1. I'm not modifiying any style or layout properties in my code! Thus I have no idea why it's not as intended in the simulator.
2. The approach from [How to show two or more label at centre of the container in codenameone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430917/how-to-show-two-or-more-label-at-centre-of-the-container-in-codenameone) didn't work for me!
3. this is my code concerning that form:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void postIntroLangSelect(Form f) {

     f.getTitleArea().setHidden(true);
     f.revalidate();

     // button configuration
     Button btnDE = findButtonDE(f);
     Button btnTR = findButtonTR(f);

     btnDE.addActionListener((e) -> {
        settings.setLocale(Lang.GERMAN);
        showNextForm();
     });      
     btnTR.addActionListener((e) -> {
       settings.setLocale(Lang.TURKISH);
       showNextForm();
     });
   }
   ```

[image: preview]
[image: running app in simulator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your form's layout to `BorderLayout` and check the `Absolute Center`, then add a container on the form with its layout constraint set to `Center`. Give this container a `BoxLayout Y` layout and add all your other components in it.

If this approach didn't work for you, then you will have to hand-code your form and set it's Layout to `new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER)`.

Comment: thanks, that worked for me! I missed to check the `Absolute Center`.

Comment: I'm still curious why my approch didn't work, since it's displayed correctly in the preview ...

Comment: I'm guessing here since there are many nuances but did you define 1 row and 1 column in the table? If not you might have created 2 rows that take up the entire screen.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog yes I did. I set a table with just one row and one column.

Comment: Could this have changed in some way? E.g. if you used the GUI builder which adds an element and then you add a new element before removing the old one...

Comment: hmm I do hide the title area, but the issue remains when I omit that. Apart from that I do not modify the container content or form content by code.